Get-PSCallStack in Windows PowerShell
I am writing a recursive function and would like to add a debugging mode with some (function) caller information along with the ScriptLineNumber.
In PowerShell 7, I am able to do something like:
MyScript.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]param()
function MyFunction($Depth = 0) {
    if ($DebugPreference -in 'Stop', 'Continue', 'Inquire') {
        $Caller = (Get-PSCallStack)[1]
        Write-Debug "Caller: $($Caller.FunctionName), Line: $($Caller.ScriptLineNumber)"
    }
    Write-Host 'Current depth:' $Depth
    if ($Depth -lt 1) { MyFunction ($Depth + 1) }
}

MyFunction   

.\MyScript.ps1 -Debug
DEBUG: Caller: <ScriptBlock>, Line: 11
Current depth: 0
DEBUG: Caller: MyFunction, Line: 8
Current depth: 1

How can I do this in Windows PowerShell 5.1?
I am lacking the C# knowledge, but I guess the answer is hidden in this C# code but I have no clue where Context.Debugger.GetCallStack() comes from...

What exactly is your question? Get-PSCallStack is already available in 5.1 ...

Your code produced the same results in both 5.1 as it did in 7.4.5.  If this isn't true for you, then maybe there is something wrong with your 5.1.

@Darin,  @MathiasR.Jessen, oops, I had a typo in my actual script: Get-CallStack rather than Get-PSCallStack (thanks for your feedback).

@iRon From Profiler? Get-CallStack requires a bp hit object from the tracer as a mandatory parameter argument, so the code you've posted would never work if we replaced Get-PSCallStack with Get-CallStack. If you're referring to a different module, please tell us which one :)

Before answering I should point out that Get-PSCallStack is available in Windows PowerShell 5.1, and hasn't changed since - so this exercise is likely entirely futile.


I am lacking the C# knowledge, but I guess the answer is hidden in this C# code but I have no clue where Context.Debugger.GetCallStack() comes from...

Context is a protected member of PSCmdlet (or rather, its ancestor class InternalCommand), which is why you can invoke it from an instance method declared by a derived type (like the GetPSCallStackCommand class).
Since we don't have access to non-public member from inside a PSScriptCmdlet, we'll need a bit of reflection magic:
function Get-PSScriptCallStack {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param() 

    $nonPublicInstanceFlags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'Instance,NonPublic'
    
    $member_psCmdletContext = $PSCmdlet.GetType().GetMembers($nonPublicInstanceFlags).Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Context' })[0]
    $contextInstance = $member_psCmdletContext.GetValue($PSCmdlet, @())
    
    $member_contextDebugger = $contextInstance.GetType().GetMembers($nonPublicInstanceFlags).Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Debugger' })[0]
    $debuggerInstance = $member_contextDebugger.GetValue($contextInstance, @())

    # Debugger.GetCallStack() is public
    $debuggerInstance.GetCallStack()
}

